# Root transform has no multi dof joint config

Tags: ros, urdf, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I try to construct a KinematicModel with my urdf, planning_environment throws the error:

"Root transform has no multi dof joint config"

My launch file attempts to launch the planning_environment environment_server, and includes multi_dof_joints.yaml, but it doesn't appear they're working correctly.

Which joint should be the multi dof joint? Or, is there some other problem of which I'm not aware?

EDIT:
My biggest confusion on this arises from the following in KinematicModel:

Constructor passes in urdf, then:
const urdf::Link *root = model.getRoot().get();
root_ = buildRecursive(NULL, root, multi_dof_configs);

The first line in build recursive:
JointModel *joint = constructJointModel(link->parent_joint.get(), link, multi_dof_configs);
This passes the model root in as "link".

In constructJointModel(const urdf::Joint *urdf_joint,                                                                                             const urdf::Link *child_link,
const std::vector& multi_dof_configs):
"link" is passed in as the child_link, which is compared against all the multi-dof child_frame_ids.

Doesn't this mean that in order for this to work, my model root must be listed as a child_frame_id in my multi_dof_joints.yaml?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11250/root-transform-has-no-multi-dof-joint-config/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-09-20**:
Your model root must be the child_frame_id - if it's not you'll get an error.  The parent_frame_id should either be your model_root, or an odometric frame.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-09-20**:
Diamondback. I'm doing this outside the arm navigation stack-- just trying to get environment server running with the correct joints/links/etc. I think the wizard is only for electric, right? I'll edit the question with a little more info on my problem.

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-09-19**:
What version of planning_environment are you using - electric or diamondback?  Did you run the arm navigation wizard?  In general the parent_frame_id should be your odometric frame if you are planning to move your base.  If not, you can just make it the first link in your urdf.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-09-19**:
I "fixed" the issue, but something is not quite right about the way KinematicModel interacts with my urdf. In my multi_dof_joints, I changed the child_frame_id of each of my joints to "world". The parent_frame_id is "baseLink". That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your model root must be the child_frame_id - if it's not you'll get an error. The parent_frame_id should either be your model_root, or an odometric frame. - egiljones

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0